# Quarkus YAML config is not injected

Tags: java, yaml, quarkus

Was trying to use YAML for my configs with Quarkus, and it looks like there's an issue with injecting config values to `@ConfigProperty`.

How to reproduce

1. Create sample project

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.12.2.Final:create \
    -DprojectGroupId=org.acme \
    -DprojectArtifactId=getting-started \
    -DclassName="org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResource" \
    -Dpath="/hello"
cd getting-started
```

2. Update `GreetingResource`

```
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {
    @ConfigProperty(name = "org.acme.getting.started.value")
    String value;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "value " + value;
    }
}
```

3. Add `application.properties`

```
org.acme.getting.started.value=8
```

4. Start the application and check the endpoint. It works

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev

curl http://localhost:8080/hello
value 8
```

5. Add YAML config support

```
./mvnw quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="config-yaml"
```

6. Delete `application.properties` and create `application.yaml`.

```
"org.acme.getting.started.value": "8"
```

7. Start the app

```
mvn clean
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

```
2021-03-18 01:30:32,890 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: No config value of type [java.lang.String] exists for: org.acme.getting.started.value
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigRecorder.validateConfigProperties(ConfigRecorder.java:39)
```

I checked both [quarkus config docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#yaml) and [smallrye docs](https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-config/config-sources/config-sources.html#yaml-config-source), didn't find any special requirements for YAML config mapping there. Also tried different formats for `application.yaml`:  quoted names, unquoted names, single-line, multi-line. None of those worked.

Is there anything I'm missing? Or should I report a bug?

**UPD** I tried breaking it down to multiline YAML like (in a way I would like to have it in my real app)

```
org:
  acme:
    getting.started:
        value: 8
```

tried both quoted and unquoted, none of those worked. In order to make it work, you need to put each new key part to a new line, see @Roberto Cortez answer

Comment: The docs don't say that you may merge levels in YAML keys (this is not a YAML feature, though it may be familiar for Java folks because Spring does it), so it could be possible that you need to do `org: {acme: {getting: {started: {value: "8"} } } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the YAML configuration to work it needs to defined like:

```yaml
org:
  acme:
    getting:
      started:
        value: 8
```

This is related with https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11744